# Angular change direction with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change direction from rtl to ltr by click .

```
<link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common.css" ng-if="!mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common-ltr.css" ng-if="mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in **setting.html**

```
<input class="" id="dir" type="checkbox" ng-model="mustCahnge">
```

but it's not working !
am i missing something ?

Comment: you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector)

Comment: "By click" - Clicking what?

Comment: input checkbox @callmekatootie

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected.
make sure

```
<link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common.css" ng-if="!mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common-ltr.css" ng-if="mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" />
```

above code is present inside the controller.

Comment: there is parent controller that include <link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common.css" ng-if="!mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" /> <link href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common-ltr.css" ng-if="mustCahnge" rel="stylesheet" />

and there is a partial view that include <input class="" id="dir" type="checkbox" ng-model="mustCahnge">