# ng-if not working in partial view - Angular

Tags: angularjs

there is header controller and partial view in my page , like :

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="headerCtrl">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common.css" data-ng-if="!isRTL">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App/Common/Style/Common/common-ltr.css" data-ng-if="isRTL">

</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

**partial view**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="directionSetting">
        <p class="pull-left">RTL</p>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isRTL" />
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to change direction after click on checkbox, but it's not working !
but if i add this in body, it's working. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular change direction with ng-if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754106/angular-change-direction-with-ng-if)

Comment: that's not clear that's why i ask one more time

Comment: isRTL is written to a child scope in this case. A good way to ensure this won't happen is to use the Controller as syntax, then use "ctrlAsName.isRtl" instead.

Comment: i've use this, but not working
would u please see this : http://themicon.co/theme/angle/v1.6.1/#/app/dashboard

Comment: there is an option for rtl and they're doing it like me

Comment: example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WVdH6rhzxXDtdxT8stXR?p=preview
(although that just changes colors of the background, it shows that styles are loaded and unloaded)

Comment: yeah and thank but there is one controller in your plnkr but i got many controller

Comment: That is irrelevant, but I have added a controller to demonstrate, I think your trouble lies in that you don't quite understand the scopes in angular etc... As your most likely running into one of the most common pitfalls in angular.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68128/discussion-between-user3642164-and-jens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be the common child scope problem in angular.

working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WVdH6rhzxXDtdxT8stXR?p=preview

Important parts:

```
<html ng-app="demo" ng-controller="siteController as site">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ltr.css" ng-if="!site.isRtl" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.rtl.css" ng-if="site.isRtl" />
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="bodyController as body">
```

It's ok that your trying to use a controller, but your binding binds directly to the scope, this means that when you try to bind that with an ng-model in a partial view, your breaking the prototypical inheritance and writes the value directly to a child scope. It's a longer and more complex thing to explain though.

I prefer to use the controller as syntax as it helps to ensure that this does not happen, you can read more about that here: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because browser will ignore the directive and load both stylesheets.

A solution could be to namespace the stylesheets, e.g.

```
.my-class {
    color: blue;
    margin-top: 10px;
    // other defaults for this class
}
.rtl .my-class {
    color: green;
    // just the differences for the special needs of RTL
}
```

and in your body or html you add

```
<body ng-class="{rtl: isRTL}">
    ...
</body>
```

If you use a CSS preprocessor like [less](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/), the namespacing is a lot easier.

Comment: thx a lot , but would you please see this ? http://themicon.co/theme/angle/v1.6.1/#/app/dashboard  
they're changing direction like me .

Comment: so yo mean i should removed the ng-if ?

Comment: OK, the link you provided proves that it generally works with ng-if, so I was wrong. They use `$rootScope.layout` object and not a controller like you did. You could test whether it better works with `$rootScope`.